# Adjunct domain and Argument domain

Tags: grammar, dependency-grammar, adjuncts

I am attempting a problem with anaphora resolution. I need help with some terms in the [Lappin and Leass'](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/J94-4002) paper.

In the paper, it is mentioned

> A pronoun P is non-coreferential with a (non-reflexive or non-reciprocal) noun phrase N if any of the following conditions hold
>
> 1. P and N have incompatible agreement features.
> 2. P is in the argument domain of N.
> 3. P is in the adjunct domain of N.
> 4. P is an argument of a head H, N is not a pronoun, and N is contained
>      in H.
> 5. P is in the NP domain of N.
> 6. P is a determiner of a noun Q, and N is contained in Q.

Examples:
[image: Some Examples]

The problem:

As far I know,

**Adjuncts** are not necessary to give meaning to the sentence, they just add more information. i.e. omission of adjuncts doesn't change the meaning of the sentence.

**Arguments** are necessary. Their omission may cause a change in meaning os sentence. (They basically are complements right?)

1. So what does an argument domain and adjunct domain mean? And how do I classify them?
2. Is there another way to differentiate arguments and adjuncts? I need to teach it to a computer.
3. What does *head* mean?
4. Again what is *domain* of noun phrase?
5. Could someone please elaborate the 6th point.

Comment: This question could be difficult to answer because it contains several questions at once. Consider splitting it into several separate ones.

Comment: The real question is whether it could be made more difficult and confusing; this is a good start, though.

Comment: Head is a lexical or functional (like CP or TP) head that projects. So, if you have a verb like "run", it will be the head V(0) projecting a VP adhering to X'-theory.